# How to connect to a running instance of Outlook from Python

Tags: python, outlook

I'm trying to write a Python script to extract data from messages in Outlook 2013 folders.
The method described everywhere to access Outlook is to first run:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

This works fine if Outlook is NOT running. But if it is, this throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None)
```

Based on a similar issue reported for another application which does not support running multiple instances at the same time either, I tried adapting their solution:

```
try:
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
except:
    app = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
```

But this does not work either. GetActiveObject now fails with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 79, in GetActiveObject
    dispatch = pythoncom.GetActiveObject(resultCLSID)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)
```

So what would be the correct way to connect to a running instance of Outlook?

Answer (score 12):

Answering my own question:

The root cause was that I was running Python in a command window running as Administrator.
If I start cmd.exe as a normal user, things work without error.
I wish GetActiveObject() would return a more meaningful error message in this case!

Side note: Reversing the two alternatives works faster:

```
try:
    outlook = win32com.client.GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
except:
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
```

Comment: I confirm. Script needs to be run with the same elevation as outlook is. 
Tried both ways with success:
1. cmd as user  &  outlook as user 
2. outlook and cmd as admin

Comment: Excellent catch - I just ran into the exact same issue when running as admin.

Comment: This StackOverflow Q/A saved me a lot of time debugging this ambiguous error message.  Thank you!

Comment: The script does not work if Outlook is open. Only one instance is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook is a singleton, so no matter what you do, it will always connect to the running instance. The only problem (as you have discovered) is that if is already running under a different security context, COM system will refuse to marshal COM objects between the two processes.

Comment: I have the same problem with Excel.Application!   Can't assign COM object, when working with multiprocessing.   It works well with one process, but not with several. And its strange, because excel was opened during the work of the same process, that is tying to find it...  But does not find.    Is it solved somehow?

Comment: Nope, running both processes in the same security context is the only solution.